# Install tensorflow windows - python conflict

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, installation

I'm trying to install tensorflow on a windows 7 machine running anaconda python 2.7.13.

```
C:\>python -V
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

I start by :

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7
```

This prompts me to proceed, I say yes and it installs several packages without issue (all seem to point to a 2.7 version of python).

Next I use :

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Which gives me this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 2.7*
  - tensorflow -> python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

EDIT: I also tried this:

```
C:\>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Next:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

and got this error message:

```
tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platf
orm.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use Python 2.7? If you start with:

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6
```

you should be able to install it how you are trying to, and run the latest release to boot! Otherwise, you might try [installing TensorFlow r0.12.1 with `pip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation):

```
$ source activate tensorflow
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

If you need GPU support, replace the `export` line in the above with:

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I think since TF 1.0.1 came out, `pip` is the preferred installation method. If I had to guess, they changed the packages available through `conda-forge` and the newest version does not work with Python 2.7 (or at least that version is not available on conda-forge). I could be wrong, but this should get you there either way.

Comment: Probably `python=3.5` would be fine as well.

Comment: Are you using Linux / Unix or Windows?

Comment: Should work the same on either. You might have to add a PATH environment variable pointing to Anaconda's executables if you get an error about there being no `pip` command.